# Different google map locations for different pages

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I got a simple website about different coffees, now each coffee type has its own page once clicked on. I would like each page to show their unique locations on a google map, this means multiple LatLng coordinates.

I currently have the same location for all the pages...

I am working on Angular 6, and am using the AGM (Angular Google Maps) package from npm (Node Package Manager).

Here is the snippet of the hard coded data in my coffee-detail.html:

Show Me

```
<agm-map [latitude]="59.326242" [longitude]="17.8419719">
   <agm-marker [latitude]="59.326242" [longitude]="17.8419719"></agm-marker>
   <agm-info-window>place</agm-info-window>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: If yours "coffee" are objects like {id:1,name:"Hard Rock cafee",lat:59.32,long:17.84}, you can use [latitude]="cofee.lat" and [longitude]="cofee.long"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a reusable component that you will place your code there and pass every time the coordinates as `@Inputs()`. Then you will use as `<reusable-compoennt [lat]='your-lat' [lon]='your-lon'></reusable-component>`

map.component.ts

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lon">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lon"></agm-marker>
        <agm-info-window>place</agm-info-window>
</agm-map>

export class MapComponent  {
  @Input() lat: string;
  @Input() lon: string;
}
```

And then use it as in app.component.html:

```
<map [lat]="lat1" [lon]="lon1"></map>

<hr>

<map [lat]="lat2" [lon]="lon2"></map>
```

app.component.ts:

```
lat1: number = 51.678418;
lon1: number = 7.809007;

lat2: number = 59.326242;
lon2: number = 17.8419719;
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zugi9v)

Make sure you use **your** **api key** cause I have removed mine in app.module.ts

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you. I implemented this in a seperate .html component from the app as a whole.

Comment: I created a generic example to demonstrate it to you. Then you can adjust it using your data. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: I did so @kboul

Comment: Thank you very much. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out with some external help.

In the place of the hard coded coordinates I set a (coffee.place.lat) and a (coffee.place.lng)
This allowed me to use a defined object, "place", deriving from a .ts file for the coffee.

So the place object would look something like this in the coffee-list.ts file:

{name: Nescafe, place: {lat: 59.326242, lng: 59.326242}}       //this would be for one coffee type